# Reducing a non regular graph to a regular one.

Tags: graph-theory

I'm not a big expert in graph theory, I know basic algorithms, but I'm not quite familiar with proofs, here. I do wonder about the following (I came up with this problem, and I don't know whether or not is true).
Let $G$ be a connected graph such that $\delta(G) = 5$ and $\Delta(G) = 6$, then there's a spanning subgraph (i.e. obtained only by edge removal), such that it is 3-regular. In general what I've tried is assuming I'm removing an edge, but from there I get confused on what happens with the neighbours. As counter example I'm not able to come up with an example (I really get confused drawing all the lines etc. The question in general is given a graph $G$ such that $\delta(G) = p, \Delta(G) = q$ can $G$ be reduced to a $r-regular$ graph by edge removal only?

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy way to show this can't be true for your initial case. Take any graph with $\delta(G)=5$, $\Delta(G)=6$ and an odd number of vertices (e.g. $G=K_{5,6}$). Now if we could remove edges to leave a $3$-regular graph we would have a $3$-regular graph with an odd number of vertices, which is impossible by handshaking.

In fact the graph given above, $K_{5,6}$, cannot be reduced to *any* regular graph by removing edges (except by removing all the edges). This is because any $r$-regular bipartite graph for $r>0$ has the same number of vertices in each part*, but any graph you can get to by removing edges from $K_{5,6}$ is bipartite with a different number of vertices in each part. This generalises to any $p,q,r$ with $p\neq q$.

* is true because if the parts have $a$ and $b$ vertices, the number of edges is $ra$ counting edges leaving the first part, but $rb$ counting the edges entering the second part, so $a=b$ or $r=0$.

Comment: What about if the number of vertices is assumed to be even?

Comment: @user8469759 You can just take two copies of $K_{p,q}$ and that will have an even number of vertices and no way to make it $r$-regular by removing edges. And it's easy to make that connected if you want by taking edges $uv$ in the first copy and $xy$ in the second and replacing them with edges $uy$ and $xv$.

Comment: I'll meditate on your comments and answer, thank you.